# Hide logic that class conforms to protocol

Tags: ios, swift3

Are there any ways to hide that class conforms to some protocol? Like in **Objective-C** - just used to add Protocol in `.m` file and other classes (from another files) didn't see it.

For example. I have a test cell which has a textfield. I want to hide, that this cell conforms to protocol. Something like that:

```
class TestCell: UITableViewCell {

}

fileprivate extension TestCell : UITextFieldDelegate {

}
```

But compiler swears me. Any elegant solution?

Comment: I'm curious why would you want to hide this?

Comment: @Essenceofchicken thats other classes don't see implementation - Encapsulation

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good approach to encapsulation. What benefit do you gain? You make it even harder to test the code.

Comment: @MartínMarconcini This Protocol only needs for private textfield, for example and  why do I have to show this anyone else?

Comment: Use composition, compose a private TextFieldDelegate, inject it, abstract, etc. I still fail to see what the problem is, that's like saying "I'm a UITableViewCell, but I want this fact to be private". It's a system class, it's ok. Plus, the framework needs to know this, otherwise, how is it going to call your delegate calls? I really want to hear a good reason behind this (you may have one, but I have never heard of this, so I'm curious).

Comment: What does it matter if other classes see it or not? Its not really encapsulation. Just because you read some buzzwords in a book doesn't mean you have to implement it. Explain what harm exactly can come if other classes can see this?If there is something terrible that can happen then its great to hide. What terrible thing might happen?

Answer (score 6):

This capability has been stated by the Swift team as "unlikely" to be implemented.  Here is the original thread about it: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160229/011666.html

The specific statement about this particular scenario was:

> Private conformances
>
> Right now, a protocol conformance can be no less visible than the
>   minimum of the conforming type’s access and the protocol’s access.
>   Therefore, a public type conforming to a public protocol must provide
>   the conformance publicly. One could imagine removing that restriction,
>   so that one could introduce a private conformance:
>
> ```
> public protocol P { } 
> public struct X { }
> extension X : internal P { … } // X conforms to P, but only within this module
> ```
>
> The main problem with private conformances is the interaction with
>   dynamic casting. If I have this code:
>
> ```
> func foo(value: Any) {
>     if let x = value as? P { print(“P”) } 
> }
> foo(X())
> ```
>
> Under what circumstances should it print “P”? If foo() is defined
>   within the same module as the conformance of X to P? If the call is
>   defined within the same module as the conformance of X to P? Never?
>   Either of the first two answers requires significant complications in
>   the dynamic casting infrastructure to take into account the module in
>   which a particular dynamic cast occurred (the first option) or where
>   an existential was formed (the second option), while the third answer
>   breaks the link between the static and dynamic type systems—none of
>   which is an acceptable result.