# How do I hide Apple's delegate functions in my class from outside users of my class?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have the following class:

```
class Scanner: NSObject, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {}
```

It has a delegate method implemented in the class from `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`:

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)
    {}
```

Even when I set the function to `private`, `fileprivate`, or `internal`, it still appears in the code-complete in Xcode:

[image]

Is there a way to hide this call from outside class use?

Comment: Once a class (type) conforms to a protocol, it guarantees that the methods from the protocol are available in that type. If you don't want the method to be accessible, then you need to remove the protocol conformance, but then I assume you run into other issues :)

Comment: If you set a Cocoa delegate method to private, you’ll hide it from Cocoa and it won’t be called! This method _depends_ on its visibility. Sorry but that’s how things are.

Comment: I understand. But why isn't there an option in Swift to hide it? Users of my class don't need access to `captureOutput`. It's only used internally to the class. I don't want to make nested classes just to hide it.

Comment: @EthanAllen the protocol comes with a contract that needs to be followed, and that contract includes the `captureOutput` method. Your class conforms to the protocol, which basically says that the class satisfies all (non-optional) requirements of that protocol. So once you declare the protocol conformance, everyone knows that the class has a `captureOutput`, it doesn't make much sense to hide it.

Comment: @matt I don't think you can declare as `private` a method that is part of a protocol conformance, unless that protocol is already private.

Comment: @Cristik You can declare it private if it isn’t a required method (nonoptional, as you rightly say).  But then, as I say, poor old Cocoa loses track of it.

Comment: @matt yeah, but where's the fun in that? :)

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51305873/is-there-a-way-to-declare-protocol-property-as-private, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020115/conform-to-protocol-and-keep-property-private, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40871194/hide-logic-that-class-conforms-to-protocol/40871832

Comment: Well, it’s actually quite desirable. If my class implements a table view delegate method, I want to make it clear to all and sundry that they must not call it. Yet I am forced to make it public, or at least internal. It’s very unpleasant.

Comment: @matt well, if you don't make it accessible how do you expect for the table view to be able to call it?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to create a private inner class that conforms to the protocol, and have the inner class hold a weak reference to the outer class, in case you need to use members from the outer class in the implementation of the delegate method.

```
class Scanner {
    ...

    private class VideoOutputDelegate: NSObject, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
        weak var scanner: Scanner?
        init(scanner: Scanner) { self.scanner = scanner }

        func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
            ...
        }
    }

    private let videoOutputDelegate = VideoOutputDelegate(scanner: self)
}
```

Rather than setting the `sampleBufferDelegate` to `self`, you can set it to `videoOutputDelegate` instead.

(I think), `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` holds a weak reference to its `sampleBufferDelegate`, so `videoOutputDelegate` here is the only strong reference here that is keeping the object alive.

Comment: Really? I recall trying that and finding that Cocoa couldn’t see the class. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: @matt I don't know actually. I know this works with delegates that I wrote in Swift. Do Cocoa delegates work differently?

Comment: Yes because Cocoa needs to see them, and it lives in the Objective C world.

Comment: @matt I just tried it with `UITextFieldDelegate` and it worked. A thing to keep in mind is that you should keep a reference to `VideoOutputDelegate` in the outer class because the delegate is a weak reference.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is somewhat related to the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). Basically your class tries to do one more task than needed - reacting to `AVFoundation` events, in this case the `captureOutput` method.

Recommending to split your class in two, have one class that handles all the `AVFoundation` setup/delegate, and have `Scanner` only deal with raw data. This way:

- you keep the concerns separated, which allows you to reuse the `Scanner` in other contexts too
- you might even be able to remove the `AVFoundation` dependency from the scanner, making it more independent
- you don't get the undesired functionality, as yes, a scanner doesn't need to expose `AVFoundation` delegate methods.

Also, most likely your scanner doesn't need a `AVCaptureConnection` to do its work, but unfortunately this dependency is leaked into the class due to the delegate. And splitting the responsibilities helps with this problem too.